# Get child taxonomies in loop

Tags: loop, menus

Here is the structure of taxonomies what I want to display:

[image]

Here is my HTML code loop:

```
<li>
    <a>TAXONMOY 1</a>
    <div class="dropdownContainer">
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 2</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 3</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a>TAXONMOY 2</a>
    <div class="dropdownContainer">
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 2</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div class="nav-column">
            <h3>TAXONMY CHILD 3</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 1</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 2</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 3</li>
                <li>TAXONMY CHILD CHILD 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</li>
```

- Just update my code:

  ```
          <?php
          $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                  'hide_empty' => false,
                  'parent'     => 0
              ));
          foreach ($terms as $term) {
      ?>
      <li>
          <a href="<?php get_term_link( $term, 'product_cat' );?>" style="padding: 5px 20px"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
          <?php
              $childs = get_terms('product_cat',array(
                      'hide_empty' => false,
                      'parent'     => $term->term_id
                  ));
              if(!empty($childs)){
          ?>
          <div class="dropdownContainer">
              <?php 
                  foreach ($childs as $child) {
              ?>
              <div class="nav-column">
                  <h3><?php echo $child->name ?></h3>
                  <?php
                      $c_childs = get_terms('product_cat',array(
                              'hide_empty' => false,
                              'child_of'   => $child->term_id
                          ));
                      if(!empty($c_childs)){
                  ?>                      
                  <ul>
                      <?php 
                          foreach ($c_childs as $c_child) {
                      ?>                      
                      <li>
                          <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $c_child, 'product_cat' );?>" title="<?php echo $c_child->name ?>"><?php echo $c_child->name ?></a>
                      </li>
                      <?php 
                          }//end child of child loop
                      ?>                          
                  </ul>
                  <?php 
                      }
                  ?>                      
              </div>
              <?php 
                  }
              ?>
          </div>
          <?php 
              }
          ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
  ```
- I'm note sure if there is another ways reduce the foreach loop!?

Comment: Do you asking to give complete script for that? Hey! buddy, Try to do something using [LOOP](http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/) Read this [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/) also. After you have any doubt in your code. Community will help you asap.

Comment: You forgot two important parts: _Here is the code I have so far_, and _Here is where exactly I got stuck._ Please add those to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: @toscho sorry, i just update my code!